# How to manage my greasemonkey userscripts using Git (in order to have them hosted in GitHub)

Tags: git, github, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'd like to use Git in order to facilitate the development of [my userscripts](https://greasyfork.org/en/users/2160-darkred) (21). Also, I'd like to have them hosted in GitHub too. *(using Greasemonkey with Firefox in windows 10)*.

So, my question is: what is the suggested way to manage my userscripts using Git, in order to also have them hosted in GitHub?

- **keep a separate folder** (e.g. `c:\my_scripts` which will be my repo folder) **containing copies of my userscripts files**,
  i.e. each time I change one of my userscript files (located in `gm_scripts`)
  **I'll have to manually copy it from `gm_scripts\script_subfolder` to `my_scripts`**?
- **have all my user userscripts in the same separate folder (my repo folder),

  and link them to the `gm_scripts` folder (using mklink -symbolic links- in a .bat file), as I've read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30827553/3231411)**?
- **create just one repository containing my `gm_scripts` content**?
  *(inside `gm_scripts`, apart from my 21 userscripts, I've got many other scripts installed, which I'll have to include in my `.gitignore` file)*
- **or is there any better way that I miss**?

I've noticed the repos of two authors of many userscripts: @Mottie and @jerone 
who have their many userscripts hosted in GitHub, 
yet they follow different approaches:
[Mottie's userscripts](https://github.com/Mottie/GitHub-userscripts) are **all located in the root folder of the repo (just the .js files, there are no subfolders)**, ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7jIU.jpg))
while [jerone's userscripts](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts) are located **each in its own subfolder in the repo** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4kXG.jpg)).

My guess is that Mottie has all his userscripts in the same separate folder (which is the repo), and has them **linked** to the `gm_scripts` folder,
while jerone either just **keeps a separate folder** as a repo, with copies of his scripts,
or has his repo **containing** the `gm_scripts` folder
*(but, jerone's [.gitignore](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts/blob/master/.gitignore) doesn't contain entries for those files in gm_folder that should be ignored, such as `.db`, `.wal`, `.shm`, `config.xml` and such. So, I'm not sure if that's the case)*.

Comment: I think all three solutions sound valid. I believe the actually solution you use is entirely up to your own opinion about what works better for you.

Comment: I personally put my userscripts up as Gists on gist.github.com. And then I clone each Gist separately, so I actually have a separate Git repository for each user script but I also do not have the overhead of a full GitHub repository for each one.

Comment: @poke: Thanks for offering a different way. It's very practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I (the user above referred as [@jerone](https://github.com/jerone/)) actually have two folders that I keep in sync: GreaseMonkey `gm_scripts` folder and checked-out [repo](https://github.com/jerone/UserScripts) folder on a different location.

The current folder structure on GitHub is there because I wanted to backup my scripts, just before Userscripts.org when offline. So I just copy-pasted my scripts (with folders) from the `gm_scripts` folder. Also because I've used some `@require`s before, keeping them in their corresponding folder.

I've not linked my `gm_scripts` folder to git because of using git branches for each userscript. The hassle of rebasing branches with the latest master is one reason. Another reason is that you can't work on two feature branches at the same time.

When working on a fix or new feature, I'm of-course working in the `gm_scripts` folder. When I'm happy with the live userscript changes, I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) to sync the changes to my checkout repo folder before committing the changes.

The `.gitnore` file is there, because I used Visual Studio to update the script, but I have changed to [Atom](http://atom.io) long time ago.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in details how you use Git with your userscripts. I've postied my userscripts in github (in [this repo](https://github.com/darkred/Userscripts)) following your way, and it'is indeed the most practical.